# Irritating tip appears in case of syntax error hiding the rest of my code

Tags: visual-studio-2015, syntax-error, tooltip, resharper

Anybody knows how to get rid of this thing?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Resharper, and I am not quite sure which of them this feature belongs to.

The tip appears whenever I have an error and stays there hiding my code regardless of where my cursor or mouse pointer go.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Settings | Untick "Show the 'Import namespace' action using popup"